# Pandas DataFrame to Dictionary with Tuples as Key and Values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I need help doing the following:

I have a CSV file as the following, loaded into a dataframe 'df'. There are multiple regions, different values for Memory, vCPUs and Storage corresponding to each 'Name'. There are 1700 rows in this dataframe.

[image: The dataframe with the CSV values loaded in]

**I need to create a dictionary that has the following:**

Key is a tuple with two elements: Name, and Region

Value of the dictionary is a tuple: Windows On-demand cost and Linux On demand cost

Ultimately, I want to create a program which does the following:
The user inputs a certain CPU and Ram and Storage, and the program will sort through the data and pull the Name, as well as Windows and Linux prices for that processor if there is a match, or if not, will pull the processor closest to the inputted values. Thanks!

```
Name    Region  API Memory  vCPUs   Storage Linux   Windows
0   M1 General Purpose Small    US West - NorCal    m1.small    1.7 GiB 1 vCPUs 160 GiB $0.047000 hourly    $0.078000 hourly
1   M1 General Purpose Medium   US West - NorCal    m1.medium   3.75 GiB    1 vCPUs 410 GiB $0.095000 hourly    $0.157000 hourly
2   M1 General Purpose Large    US West - NorCal    m1.large    7.5 GiB 2 vCPUs 840 GiB $0.190000 hourly    $0.314000 hourly
3   M1 General Purpose Extra Large  US West - NorCal    m1.xlarge   15.0 GiB    4 vCPUs 1680 GiB    $0.379000 hourly    $0.627000 hourly
4   C1 High-CPU Medium  US West - NorCal    c1.medium   1.7 GiB 2 vCPUs 350 GiB $0.148000 hourly    $0.228000 hourly
```

Comment: Can you post your data as simple text by copy and pasting your minified Datafrme, alogn with your expected output of the minified input dataframe? Consider refering to [MCVE]

Comment: For your ultimate goal: why do you need the dict? And how does the region and name key help?

Comment: Quickbeam - there are 15 regions, each with the same 'Names', but different prices for each region. I want the user to input their desired CPU cores, RAM, and storage, and for the program to grab all of the processors that match (or are close) to the inputted values, and output a list of the processor, and its prices in all 15 regions. I've added the copy-paste of the DataFrame to the original post.

Comment: That's fine, but it doesn't explain why you really need a dict. btw, DataFrames have a `to_dict`-function, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). Just take the subset of data you are interested in and use that function to output a dict if really needed

Comment: For my use, what should I be using rather than a dict? Sorry, new to python

Comment: @YungBas Does my code create the dictionary you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the part that creates the dictionary

```
tempDict = {}

for i in df.index:

    key = (df.at[i, 'Name'] ,df.at[i, 'Region']) #Rename columns accordingly
    value = (df.at[i, 'Windows On-demand cost'] ,df.at[i, 'Linux On demand cost']) #Rename columns accordingly

    dictionary = {key: value}
    tempDict.update(dictionary)

print(tempDict)
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Any ideas on how I would write a function to search through this dict and return the Names and prices for each region? (Given, that there are about 15 different prices for each, since each region has its own price for each name)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
outdict = {k: (gdf['Windows On Demand cost'].item(), 
               gdf['Linux On Demand cost'].item())
           for k, gdf in df.groupby(['Name', 'Region'])}
```